# Importing a deployed google web apps project

Tags: google-app-engine

I have made a rookie mistake of not backing up a project I've been working on. A quite recent version of it is currently deployed. I had to re-install the app engine launcher and was wondering if there is any way at all to download the current project from the deployed version and carry on working on it?

I do recall seeing something about this in a google developers page I can't seem to find now, and it involved using the projects number as well as its id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_source_code) is the link you're looking for. Or [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application) one if you're using Java.

It basically comes down to this command in your command line:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was precisely what I needed!